# npm installation problem - React 18 is not supported

Tags: javascript, reactjs, node-modules

When installing the `react-canvas-draw` package I am facing the following issue.

> npm ERR! While resolving: frontend@0.1.0 npm ERR! Found: react@18.2.0 npm ERR! node_modules/react npm ERR!   react@"18.2.0" from the root project npm ERR! npm ERR! Could not resolve dependency: npm ERR! peer react@"16.x || 17.x" from react-canvas-draw@1.2.1 npm ERR! node_modules/react-canvas-draw

I am using React 18 and do not want to revert to an earlier version. How do I solve this?

Comment: are you installing packages globally?

Comment: yes .. trying to install by "npm i "pacakage-name" --save

Comment: https://github.com/embiem/react-canvas-draw/issues/142 - but you might want to find a different library as this one is no longer supported or maintained.